# Eclipse Luna C++ endl

Tags: c++, eclipse, cout, eclipse-luna, endl

I just started learning C++ and I noticed that when I do `cout << "Some text" << endl;`  endl is not bold. I want to make sure that this is not a problem and it won't cause any future problems.

Comment: Does it insert a newline? If yes, why should it be a problem?

Comment: @nbro: *ouch*… a common misunderstanding is that `endl` is what you use when you want a newline… `'\n'` is there for that particular purpose. `std::endl` does two things, it adds a newline and it *flushes* the stream, which can cause a performance penalty. A friend taught me that you should never use `endl`, but rather `'\n'` for newline, and if you want to *flush*, do it explicitly with `std::flush`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Why is there a `std::endl` then?

Comment: @nbro: It was initially added to create similar behavior for streams as setting `_IOLBF` on a stream. The assumption was that it would be used where a newline and a flush would be needed and nowhere else. Instead, people advertised it in books as a way spell newline! This misrepresentation resulted in a lot of C++ code interacting with files being extremely slow. So far I have found severe performance problems related to inappropriate use of `std::endl` at three major locations I have worked at (out of a total of 5 where at two of them the code in the project wasn't really using C++...).

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** (<---- this intentionally bold!) use `std::endl`! Ever. It has no place in C++. It was a good idea but it is being abused. If you want a newline, use `'\n'`. If you want a flush, use a `std::flush`. [Here](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) is a more thorough explanation.

I don't know about Eclipse but I'd assume that it highlight keywords in bold: `std::endl` isn't a keyword. It is just a function (well, actually it is a function template but the details really don't matter) with a specific signature (`std::ostream&(std::ostream&)`) pointers to which are treated special when using it with an output operator on a `std::ostream`: the operator will just call the function with the stream as argument. These functions are called *manipulators*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the `endl` stuff, I did not know about it :D

Comment: The only reason I asked is because I saw this video and wondered why mine wasn't bold https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Enqpi4trl8&list=PLmpc3xvYSk4wDCP5zjt2QQXe8-JGHa4Kt&index=4  Thanks for the explanation.